# Why is Turtle SetX not working? Python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, pong

I'm currently trying to make pong using turtle. Everything seems to be going well, but for some reason this single line isn't working.

```
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
```

It's in the main loop of the script, and sety works. I get the following errors relating to it.

```
File "C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Python\Pong.py", line 71, in <module>
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
```

and this one, which is in the turtle module script.

```
 File "C:\Users\Ross\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\turtle.py", line 1808, in setx
```

I'm not exactly sure what's going on. Any solutions or ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: We need to see the full error message. You chopped off the part that actually tells you what went wrong.

Comment: That's it. I posted the entirety of both error messages.